# YouTube player android code, how programmatically know when video quality changes?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to know, how to get the video quality or the bitrate in YouTube android player, when the quality of the video changes?
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the YouTube Android player, there is no direct way to retrieve the video quality or bitrate when the video quality changes. The YouTube API for Android does not provide specific methods or events to capture such information. The API primarily focuses on playback control rather than accessing detailed video quality information.